# Question bumped into Community Wiki by several bounties?

Tags: bug, bounties, community-wiki

Look at the [revision history of this here question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/47086/revisions) — what concerns me is the entry that says:

> **Post Made Community Wiki** by being edited by more than 5 different editors

If you look at the revisions, you'll see that this isn't actually true. It was edited by just 2 people, and then a bunch of stuff happened, and then suddenly *bam*, Community Wiki.

It looks like some events related to bounties are being counted as edits by the "should this be CW" check. Is this working as designed?

Comment: [Something special](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/what-the-heck) happened there. (And by "special" I mean "bad").

Comment: Probably my bug - looking at it.

Comment: @JarrodDixon, one of the mods CW'ed the post manually, so it's probably not a bug in the auto-CW code, just that the system picked it up funny.